# AWS Lambda Base image: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0 403 Forbidden

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a container image based on AWS's provided lambda [base image](https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs). However I'm suddenly getting a 403 Forbidden error. I was able to successfully build this image a few days ago whe I last tried, but I haven't changed anything in my dockerfile.
Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:latest
COPY index.js ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
CMD [ "index.handler" ]
```

The logs from the build:

```
=> ERROR [internal] load metadata for public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:latest                                                                              
0.3s 
------
> [internal] load metadata for public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:latest:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: unexpected status code [manifests latest]: 403 Forbidden
```

Comment: Do you use MAC M1?